# How to set vertical text on PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

How can I set vertical align to the text on PHPExcel

I tried with

```
$phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2:B5')->getAlignment()->setReadorder(
            PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::READORDER_RTL
        );
```

But it didn't work.

I actually have:

```
THE TEXT
```

But I want

```
T
H
E

T
E
X
T
```

Like the image.

[image: Vertical text]

Answer (score 1):

It's not vertical alignment that you want to look at: vertical alignment is whether the content should be at the top/centre/bottom of a cell; nor RTL, which is Right-to-Left. You could perhaps look at text rotation, but that rotates the orientation of the text.

You'll always need to set the row height to automatic and enable wrapping.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getRowDimension(12)
    ->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

so that it will expand to the actual size of your text.

Then an option would be to add a new line character after every character in your string before setting the cell value:

```
$value = "THE TEXT";
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('A1', implode("\n", str_split($value)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I See what your problem is,

I have solution for you , you still using `getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);` on your code, but you can add variable that fill is "\n" for every value you want it.

For Example :

```
 $n= "\n";

 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A','T'.$n.'E'.$n.'S'.$n.'T');

 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

result's as bellow:

T 
E 
S 
T

Hope this answer can help you.